# How do I restrict a post-commit hook?

Tags: security, svn, ubuntu-10.04

Yesterday, I mistakenly wrote a post-commit hook that fatally broke my server. In fact, when I committed via TortoiseSVN, I could see the post-commit hook remove significant system resources. When I tried to reboot the server, the server did not boot.

Anyway, I'm about to setup SVN again, and I don't want to make the same mistake. How do I restrict my post-commit hook permissions to only be able to modify certain folders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What user is SVN running as?

On my system, SVN is running with the Apache user via DAV, so the user it is running as is `www-data`, so it wouldn't have access to critical system resources outside the scope.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure who SVN itself was running as. I know I was committing under my user that I setup, which does have extensive permissions. Does the post-commit hook get run under the permissions of the committer or as the permissions of the SVN executable? I setup SVN using this guide: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Subversion

Comment: Yes. If you're using the direct access method, it will run as the user you login with. I would suggest making the switch to WebDAV, so that commits/hooks will run as www-data, which will prevent a bad hook from causing any system wide problem.